# How to debug webpack project in typescript files not output bundle file running on webpack-dev-server in VSCode

Tags: typescript, webpack, visual-studio-code, webpack-dev-server, vscode-debugger

How to debug webpack project in original typescript source files not output bundle file that are running on webpack-dev-server in VSCode by using [VSCode's built in JavaScript Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will be able to achieve it like this in the end.
[image]

**webpack.config.ts**

```
import Webpack from "webpack";
import Path from "path";

const factory: Webpack.ConfigurationFactory = (env, args): Webpack.Configuration => {
    const outputPath = Path.resolve(__dirname, "build");
    const config: Webpack.Configuration = {
        output: {
            path: outputPath
        },
        devtool: "source-map", // this is a key point, this option makes browser catch breakpoints faster than "inline-source-map"
        devServer: {
            // don't need writeToDisk="true"
            contentBase: outputPath,
            hot: true,
            liveReload: false,
        }
    };

    return config;
};

export default factory;
```

**tsconfig.json *!super important***

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "sourceMap": true // if not set, breakpoints will point wrong lines
    }
}
```

**launch.json**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "pwa-chrome", // note this is not just "chrome" as the debugger is "JavaScript Debugger"
            "name": "Attach Chrome",
            "port": 9222,
            // depending on your preference, you may want to set the request option as 'launch'.
            // you may want to set the request option as 'launch'
            "request": "attach",
            // if the request option is 'launch' then this option should be changed to "url": "localhost:3000"
            // note that the port number should be the one you set on devServer.port in webpack.config
            "urlFilter": "localhost:3000",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/frontend", // make the path match your project
        },
    ]
}
```

For more information about how you should set launch.json: [Debugger for Chrome](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=msjsdiag.debugger-for-chrome)

Although it's not [JavaScript Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug), they share most of the configuration as VSCode has just moved javascript debugging tool from `Debugger for Chrome` to `JavaScript Debugger`, so you can just refer to the description on the link.